# Cast issue while reading streams with pyspark

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, aws-glue

I'm using Glue to read stream with spark

```py
try:
    options = {
      "kafka.sasl.jaas.config": 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="XXXXXXXXXXXX" password="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";',
      "kafka.sasl.mechanism": "PLAIN",
      "kafka.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
      "kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-server:9092",
      "subscribe": "masterstaging_cfr_out_customeragreement_event_disbursement_ini",
        "startingOffsets":"latest"
    }
    df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load()
    
    df=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    df.writeStream.format("json") \
      .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://output/")\
      .outputMode("append") \
      .option("path",  "s3://output/") \
      .start() \
      .awaitTermination()
      
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

In the outout I got the following json format

```json
{
  "key": "test",
  "value": "{\n  \"payload\": {\n    \"EventCode\": {\n      \"operation_code\": \"Creation\",\n      \"reason_code\": \"\"\n    },\n    \"Data\": \n      \"id\": 8888881,\n      \"ref\": \"D16/0405\" 
 \n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

I don't want to get the `\`,

How to cast properly the `value` as json ?

```
df=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to encounter this problem when reading the String `value` with pyspark.

To read this json input

```json
{
  "key": "test",
  "value": "{\n  \"payload\": {\n    \"EventCode\": {\n      \"operation_code\": \"Creation\",\n      \"reason_code\": \"\"\n    },\n    \"Data\": \n      \"id\": 8888881,\n      \"ref\": \"D16/0405\" 
 \n    }\n  }\n}"
}
```

we need to use the function `from_json`

we can use the following approach

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StructType,
    StructField,
    StringType
)
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

--

schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("key", StringType(), True),
            StructField("value", StringType() , True),
        ]
    )
--

url = "C://Users/user/my_json_file_url"
df = spark.read.schema(schema).option("multiLine", "false").json(url)
# df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- key: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- value: string (nullable = true)

--
# retrieve programaticaly the schema
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.value)).schema
df = df.withColumn('json', f.from_json(f.col('value'), json_schema))

df.select("json.*").show()
```